# Leftover change amount using modulus operator (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, modulus

I am working on an assignment that requires me to convert any number of pennies into the appropriate amount of Quarters, Dimes, Nickels and remaining pennies.

When I run the program, it is converting the total amount to each respective coin using `Math.floor()`. This script is running in the head, as is required per the assignment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Make Change</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.29" />

<script>
function convertChange(numberOfQuarters, numberOfDimes, numberOfNickels, numberOfPennies) {

number=parseFloat(document.getElementById("penniesBox").value);
numberOfQuarters = Math.floor(number/25);
numberOfDimes = Math.floor(number/10);
numberOfNickels = Math.floor(number/5);
numberOfPennies = Math.floor(number/1);
    document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML=
        'Quarters: ' + numberOfQuarters + "<br>" + 
        'Dimes: ' + numberOfDimes + "<br>" + 
        'Nickels: ' + numberOfNickels + "<br>" + 
        'Pennies:' + numberOfPennies;

}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Make Change</h2>
<p>This page will tell you the minimum amount of pennies, nickels, dimes and quarters you need to match the number of pennies entered.</p>
<p>Enter a number of pennies:
<input type="text" id="penniesBox" size=12 value="">
</p>
    <input type="button" value="Show me the money!"
    onclick="convertChange();">


<hr>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>




</body>

</html>
```

How would I go about using the modulus operator in order to get the remaining amount of pennies to display next to the appropriate amount of change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use modulus to get the leftover amount that you'll use in later calculations (`Math.floor...`), overwriting each money with the leftover amount. Also, since you're not passing in the variables to your function in your onclick (notice it's only `convertChange()`), you should declare your variables within the function using `var ...`.

See updated code here:

```js
function convertChange() {
    var money = parseFloat(document.getElementById("penniesBox").value); 
    var numberOfQuarters = Math.floor(money/25);
    money = money%25;
    var numberOfDimes = Math.floor(money/10);
    money = money%25;
    var numberOfNickels = Math.floor(money/5);
    money = money%5;
    var numberOfPennies = money;
        document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML=
            'Quarters: ' + numberOfQuarters + "<br>" + 
            'Dimes: ' + numberOfDimes + "<br>" + 
            'Nickels: ' + numberOfNickels + "<br>" + 
            'Pennies:' + numberOfPennies;
}
```

```html
<h2>Make Change</h2>
<p>This page will tell you the minimum amount of pennies, nickels, dimes and quarters you need to match the number of pennies entered.</p>
<p>Enter a number of pennies:
<input type="text" id="penniesBox" size=12 value="">
</p>
    <input type="button" value="Show me the money!"
    onclick="convertChange();">


<hr>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```